# Kotlin/JS - external val from npm package is undefined

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-js

I'm trying to use React components from the CKEditor package in my kotlin/js code.

In javascript, I would import these like this:

```js
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
```

I've added both dependencies to my build.gradle.kts file:

```
implementation(npm("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react","5.1.0"))
implementation(npm("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic", "36.0.1"))
```

For CKEditor, which imports fine, I made this file:

```kotlin
@file:JsModule("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react")
@file:JsNonModule

import react.*

external interface CKEditorProps : Props {
    //...
}

@JsName("CKEditor")
external val CKEditor: ComponentClass<CKEditorProps>
```

Next I have my file for ClassicEditor, though I've tried many other ways:

```kotlin
@file:JsModule("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic")
@file:JsNonModule

@JsName("default")
external val ClassicEditor: Any
```

If I print both to console, I see CKEditor is a class, seemingly imported correctly. ClassicEditor, however, is undefined.

documentation for ClassicEditor is here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-classic_classiceditor-ClassicEditor.html

I have checked gradle dependencies to be sure the dependency exists.

```
+--- @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react:5.1.0 (n)
\--- @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic:36.0.1 (n)
```

I've tried using `external class` or different types, including `dynamic`,`ComponentClass`, `FC`, etc.

I believe the @JsName should be `default`, but I've also tried using `ClassicEditor`.

I'm very new to kotlin-js, so I'm likely missing some context, but I've had no luck searching for answers online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but removing `file:` from the annotations has fixed it.

```kotlin
@JsModule("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic")
@JsNonModule
```

instead of

```kotlin
@file:JsModule("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic")
@file:JsNonModule
```